# Has anyone compiled a "dictionary" of graph theory?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, book-recommendation

I would be really interested in a book that lists out all the important special types of graphs and/or their properties.

Edit: The Wikipedia page for "List of Graph Theory Topics" is decent, but I'm hoping for something more complete and self-contained.

Comment: I like [The Theory of Graphs - Claude Berge](https://www.amazon.fr/Theory-Graphs-Claude-Berge/dp/0486785858/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2GS7X6DBZJYQL&keywords=berge+graph+theory&qid=1671299170&s=books&sprefix=berge+graph+theory%2Cstripbooks%2C91&sr=1-2)

Comment: Thanks! I already have some books on graph theory in general, but was hoping to find something that broadly captures the landscape of the field.

Comment: What's the difference between "graph theory in general" and "broadly capturing the landscape"? At first I thought [The House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/) is what you're looking for, but maybe the list you want is less specific than that; it's still not clear to me what it is you do want, though.

Comment: @MishaLavrov That's closer to what I'm looking for! Sorry I should have been more clear. What I mean is that I don't want an introductory text to the field, but rather something that covers pretty much everything in graph theory (even if not very detailed).